# Template declaration explanation

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I was looking at C++ STL vector template code to understand exactly how it is implemented.
I have very basic understanding of template programming, could you give a clear explanation of the expression

```
typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Tp>
```

excerpt from STL vector as below:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Tp> >
class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
```

Thank you for all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assigns a default type to a template parameter, so that you don't have to add it whenever you create a vector:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

By default, the second parameter of the template is filled by the type `std::allocator<_Tp>`.

Default template parameters allow to shorten data declarations by including some default functionality (that you can override by simply giving a second parameter to the declaration of the template).

Answer (score 1):

Class template parameters can have default arguments just as functions allow you to have default arguments for function parameters.

This allows you to use `std::vector` with only a single template argument, the value type, without having to specify the allocator explicitly, since most of the time you want the default allocator anyway.

This

```
std::vector<int>
```

is exactly the same as

```
std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >
```

Comment: Thanks james. Do you know if there's any article or book that will explain, the design of STL code? I want to understand how the library is designed

Comment: @reddy:  There is a [list of good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list) here on Stack Overflow.  Which would be most useful to you depends on what exactly you want to learn.